# Django rest framework and XML. Change item_tag_name, root_tag_name and other

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I set up a **rest framework** in my project according to **Quickstart**
Everything works, but, as it usually happens, not without questions!

1. My **serializer.py**:

   class kvSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

   ```
   class Meta:
       model = kv
       fields = ['title', 'price', 'address']
   ```
2. My **views.py**:

   class kvViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

   ```
   queryset = listings.objects.all()
   serializer_class = kvSerializer
   ```
3. My **XML**:

   Object title
       
       100
       
       object address

**Question:**

1. How can I change tags `<root>` and `<list-item>`?

   `<root>` should be called `<feed>`

   `<list-item>` should be called `<offer>`
2. Before tag `<offer>` need to insert tag `<creation-date>`

My final XML should be as follows:

```
<feed>
<creation-date>Date</creation-date>
<offer id=1>
    <title>
    Object title
    </title>
    <price>100</price>
    <address>
    object address
    </address>
</offer>
<offer id=2>
    <title>
    Object title
    </title>
    <price>100</price>
    <address>
    object address
    </address>
</offer>
</feed>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not part of the serializer, but of the renderer. You can alter the renderer in your `ModelViewSet`. We can install a simple renderer with:

```
pip install djangorestframework-xml
```

Then we can create a custom renderer by subclassing `XmlRenderer` and override the `_to_xml` method:

```
from rest_framework_xml.renderers import XMLRenderer

class KvXMLRenderer(XMLRenderer):
    root_tag_name = 'feed'
    item_tag_name = 'offer'
    creation_tag_name = 'creation-date'

    def _to_xml(self, xml, data):
        xml.startElement(self.creation_tag_name, {})
        xml.characters('string-of-creation-date')
        xml.endElement(self.creation_tag_name)
        super()._to_xml(xml, data)
```

We can then use our custom renderer in the `renderer_classes` of the `ModelViewSet`:

```
class kvViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = listings.objects.all()
    serializer_class = kvSerializer
    renderer_classes = [KvXmlRenderer]
```

Comment: Willem Van Onsem, Thank you! It works as it should! But does not work with tag `creation-date`, if I add _to_xml, I get an error: `startElement() missing 1 required positional argument: 'attrs'`

Comment: @I.Z.: aah yes, I forgot that you need to add an empty dictionary here as second parameter. See edit. Of course you need to alter the `string-of-creation-date` to something you want to insert in that tag.

Comment: Willem Van Onsem, thank you so much! Everything is working!